# Check Selected Product and product which is added to cart are same or not

Tags: java, selenium

I have searched for a mobile product which is of type **" Asus Zenfone 5 "** in **flipkart.com** website, search display many products. I selected first product and added it to cart.

Below is my code:

```
 @Test
 public void flipkartScript() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("fk-top-search-box")).sendKeys("Asus Zenfone 5");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Search']")).click();

    // Selecting first product
    driver.findElement(By
        .xpath(".//*[@id='products']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]"));
    String name = driver.findElement(By.className("title")).getText();
    String price = driver.findElement(By
        .xpath("//span[@class='selling-price omniture-field']")).getText();
    System.out.println("ProductName: "+name + "  ProductPrice: "+price);

    //Adding selected product to cart
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add to Cart']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    //Checking product is available in cart or not
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='cart-label']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Everything is working fine in my code.

Now my doubt is, to check if Selected product and added product both are same. Product name in cart is different from the first product Name in the search results. We can only check if the product names are same or not. Other than that, is there any other option to check? So how can we check whether the selected product is same as the product which is in the cart??

Comment: You want to check if product selected to add to cart and product actually added to cart are same or not. Is it?

Comment: Yes. That too for first product in my search result.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the product in product detail page get the page title and store it in a String

```
String product_title=driver.getTitle();
```

After adding the product to the cart in the cart page click the product image in the cart(You can also do this in another tab)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'carty-image')]/a/img")).click();

Assert.assertEquals(product_title, driver.getTitle());
```

We are comparing both the title's.In your case it should be "Asus Zenfone 5 Price in India - Buy Asus Zenfone 5 Black 8 Online - Asus : Flipkart.com" By this way you can be 100% sure that the product is the same product you selected.You can also check price in the details page and compare it with the cart page

You can also get the product attributes "Black, with 8 GB, with 1.2 GHz Processor" in detail page and compare it with the cart page

```
//product detail page
String detail_page=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='subtitle']")).getText();
//cart page     
String cart_page=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(@class,'fk-font-11')]")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(detail_page, cart_page);
```

**Edit** :

You cannot compare by using name in both product page and cart page bcoz if u look at the page source of cart page the name is "Asus A501CG-2A508WWE/ A501CG-2A584WWE Zenfone..." even if we write a regex and get the name ex : Asus zenfone we won't be able to get the full name Asus Zenfone 5 so this will not be the correct procedure to check.Only in the order summary section which appears after placing the order(clicking place order button in view cart page) you will be able to verify using the name "Asus Zenfone 5".

**Explanation about my solution** :

**Step 1** : In the search page you click the first product(asus zenfone 5)

**Step 2** : You will be redirected to the detail page of the product you selected here after selecting the features like color or storage the page will reload and after that get the page title it will be like ex : Asus Zenfone 5 Price in India - Buy Asus Zenfone 5 Red 8 Online - Asus : Flipkart.com and other features (like color, storage and processor selected),seller name

**Step 3** : click add to cart button and go to the cart page

**Step 4** : In the cart page verify whether all the features are present for checking the name the only thing you can do is click on the image of the product and open it in a new tab and then again get the title and compare it with the previous title which we got before adding the product to the cart.Thus you can verify that you have added the correct product.

You can also keep the another check to verify whether the product added is same like get the product id of the product before adding it to the cart and in the cart page get the **pid** attribute from the url and compare both of them

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any doubts

Comment: details might be same for other product also. So comparing with details is not the way. It might be result in same product. but the product may be different by having same features.

Comment: @SarithaG I can't get you. If the product on clicking redirects to the correct detail page you can be 100% sure that this is the product you selected bcoz multiple products cannot have same detail page and coming to your question about features actually in the above code we are also validating features "Black, with 8 GB, with 1.2 GHz Processor" by comparing it with cart page.Ex: if red color with 16 GB is selected it will be displayed in both detail and cart page like "Red, with 16 GB, with 1.6 GHz Processor"

Comment: This feature may be same for some other product which has different name. So comparing with details is not correct way.

Comment: But actually in this case we are comparing name also using the title if u notice "Asus Zenfone 5 Price in India - Buy Asus Zenfone 5 Black 8 Online - Asus : Flipkart.com" Do you mean to say there are multiple products using the same title ?.If it is about seller then you can get the seller name in product page and compare it with the cart page?

Comment: Yes we have to compare with name also. But here the name is different. That's what i asked in my question. Names are different how can your compare with name?

Comment: Your answer works when there is only single product available in the cart. If there are more number of products are added to cart. Then that won't work out.

Comment: No this will work for more products also because each product is added as a seperate item in cart page(Ex: even if you add zenfone 5 red and zenfone 5 black it will be added as seperate items) you can apply the solution which u applied for checking 1st item for all items.One change which u have to do is instead of storing in a string store it in a arraylist by which u can do it for n number of products.But yes it will take time to check more products because we have to open all the links.But unfortunately that is the only way as there is no full product name displayed in view cart page

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that just the Product name cannot be used to distinguish between different products as many products may have same or similar name and that may not give you the expected result.

Try Product Id instead. Use the code to compare the Product Id's.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='products']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div"))
      .getAttribute("data-pid")     //Id from first product in search result

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='compare-items']/div[1]"))
      .getAttribute("item_id"))    //Id from product added to cart
```

Also, there seems to be few dynamic XPath in your code, you may need to make it static so that test do not fail.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: What that ID will return??

Comment: @SarithaG if you search for "Asus Zenfone 5", you will get `MOBE3HYEBFRKHRGG` as product id for both first product in search with name "Asus Zenfone 5 (Black, with 8 GB, with 1.2 GHz Processor)" and one on cart.

Comment: @SarithaG did the above solution worked for you? can i help if your have any other queries?

Answer (score 0):

I think the title with mobile model number is displayed in the cart page and where as in the Product Details page, only the title of phone is displayed.

So if you want to compare both the titles:-

```
//Product Details page.
Title is = Asus Zenfone 5.
String product = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@itemprop='name']")).getText();
```

Note:- Difference in the page is "Add To Cart" Button is enable and you can click it.

//Cart Page
After clicking on mobile image icon the Title is = Asus Zenfone 5.
Click on the small Mobile image icon and it will takes to the bigger page. Then you can take get Title.

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath("//*[@class='carty-image fk-text-center fk-position-relative']/a/img")).click();
String cart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='title   Hover']")).getText();
```

Note:- Difference in the page is "Add To Cart" Button is disable, As we have already added the Item to the cart.

Now you can compare by.

```
Assert.assertEquals(product, cart);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If there are more than 100 products in the cart. Then we can't check by clicking every product..right?